# Increase Bootstrap 4 label width in modal the right way

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, label, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to increase the width of the label in a form within a Boostrap modal.  It has a max-width of max-width: 16.66667%;.  Is there a better way or class I should set this up with? As you can see the label is being overwritten and there is plenty of space to the right.  I'd rather use Bootstrap classes then my own custom ones if possible.

```
 <form class="game-score-modal" novalidate="novalidate" action="@Url.Action(Model.Score.UpdateGameUrl)" data-bind="submit: save, with: score">

.
.
.

<div class="form-row">
    <label for="EnableSubscription">Communication</label>
    <div class="col-auto">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-check active" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox" title="Send Email/Text"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> </button><input checked="checked" data-bind="value: EnableSubscription,disable: EnableSubscription() == null ? true : false, checkbox: { checked: true, iconClass: 'fa fa-comment'}" id="EnableSubscription" name="EnableSubscription" title="Send Email/Text" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="EnableSubscription" type="hidden" value="false">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-check active" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox" title="Post To Twitter"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i> </button><input checked="checked" data-bind="value: EnableTwitter,disable: EnableTwitter() == null ? true : false, checkbox: { checked: true, iconClass: 'fab fa-twitter'}" id="EnableTwitter" name="EnableTwitter" title="Post To Twitter" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="EnableTwitter" type="hidden" value="false">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-check active" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox" title="Post To Facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i> </button><input checked="checked" data-bind="value: EnableFacebook,disable: EnableFacebook() == null ? true : false, checkbox: { checked: true, iconClass: 'fab fa-facebook'}" id="EnableFacebook" name="EnableFacebook" title="Post To Facebook" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="EnableFacebook" type="hidden" value="false">

    </div>
</div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

[image]

Comment: Being a direct child of `.form-row` your `<label>` can have any combo of `col-*-*` classes. i.e: `col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-12`. Alternatively, you can simply place the `<label>` inside the `.col-auto`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treat the form as it was your bootstrap grid using column classes.

Switch from `.row` to `.form-row` when you want your gutters to be compact.

Also if your modal is purely a form then replace the `div.modal-content` with `form.modal-content` and utilise bootstraps modal classes.

For example...

```js
$('#updateScore').modal('show');
```

```html
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="updateScore">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

    <form class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Update Score</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-form-label col-sm-4 col-12 text-sm-right">Team 1</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8 col-12">
            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-4">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-8">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <label class="input-group-text">
                      Won By
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <select class="custom-select">
                    <option selected>-</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group col-12">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">
                  <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Pool Play
                </button>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">
                  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-info"></i>
                </button>

                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle-thin"></i>
                  </button>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option</a>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <hr />

        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-form-label col-sm-4 col-12 text-sm-right">Team 2</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8 col-12">
            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-4">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-8">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <label class="input-group-text">
                      Won By
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <select class="custom-select">
                    <option selected>-</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group col-12">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">
                  <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Pool Play
                </button>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">
                  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-info"></i>
                </button>

                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle-thin"></i>
                  </button>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option</a>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <hr />

        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-form-label col-sm-4 col-12 text-sm-right">Notes</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8 col-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-form-label col-sm-4 col-12 text-sm-right">Uploads</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8 col-12">
            <div class="custom-file">
              <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="uploads" required>
              <label class="custom-file-label" for="uploads">Choose file...</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-form-label col-sm-4 col-12 text-sm-right">Communication</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8 col-12">

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
              <i class="fa fa-fw fa-comment"></i>
            </button>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
              <i class="fa fa-fw fa-twitter"></i>
            </button>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
              <i class="fa fa-fw fa-facebook"></i>
            </button>

            <input type="hidden" value="false" />
            <input type="hidden" value="false" />
            <input type="hidden" value="false" />

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
          <i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Cancel
        </button>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save
        </button>

      </div>

    </form>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="container mt-3">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#updateScore">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: I wish it was a little more simpler but this worked just fine.

Comment: At least this way when in mobile this stacks your labels on top rather than side by side.